# Как подключить класс WebGuy в Codeception через Composer

Tags: php

Начал разбираться с тестами.
Создал у себя в проекте папку `test` в ней поставил через Composer Codeception

выполнил

```
$ php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception:*"
$ vendor/bin/codecept
$ sudo vi test/acceptance.suite.yml
```

В `acceptance.suite.yml` вписал

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
enabled:
- PhpBrowser:
url: http://rabota.mysite.loc/
- \Helper\Acceptance
$ ../vendor/bin/codeseption run acceptance
```

Тест выдает ошибку

> Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.1.2
> Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Acceptance Tests (1) -----------------------------------------------------------
> Trying to test front page of my site (StartPageCept)... PHP Fatal error: Class 'WebGuy' not found in /var/www/rabota.mysite.loc/tests/tests/acceptance/StartPageCept.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: Class 'WebGuy' not found in /var/www/rabota.mysite.loc/tests/tests/acceptance/StartPageCept.php on line 2
>
> FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
> Class 'WebGuy' not found
> in /var/www/rabota.mysite.loc/tests/tests/acceptance/StartPageCept.php:2

Как подключить расширение, для PHP, чтоб был класс?

Comment: StartPageCept-то приведите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выполнить

```
php ./vendor/bin/codecept build
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?